# Optional parameters in JQuery seletor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a selector in JQuery that will fade in an element on multiple lists when anywhere on the document is clicked. Right now there are two lists, `kiosks` and `profiles`. The code I'm using for the function looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click', function( e ){
    $( '.profile:not(".default") .name:not(".selected") .rename' ).fadeIn(80);
    $( '.kiosk .name:not(".selected") .rename' ).fadeIn(80);
});
```

Is there any way that I could add an optional selector, so that if the item is a profile that it also excludes the `default`, but otherwise any name uses these rules?

EDIT: What I'm trying to do is to make that function into one line, so that it would be something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', function( e ){
    $( '[profile:not("default") .name:not("selected") .rename' ).fadeIn(80);
});
```

Here is the HTML with the data bindings attached:

```
    <!-- Profiles -->
    <div class="profiles">
        <h1>Profiles</h1>
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'profilestempl', foreach: $root.profiles }"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/html" id="profilestempl">
        <div class="profile" data-bind="css: { 'default' : !canChange() }">
            <div class="name" data-bind="css: { 'selected' : isSelected }">
                <input type="text" data-bind="hasfocus: $data.isSelected, value: tempName, enable: canChange(), valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
                <span class="rename" data-bind="click: $root.selectProfile">q</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>

    <!-- Kiosks -->
    <div class="kiosks">
        <h1>Kiosks</h1>
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'kioskstempl', foreach: $root.kiosks }"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/html" id="kioskstempl">
        <div class="kiosk">
            <div class="name" data-bind=" css: { 'selected' : isSelected }">
                <input type="text" maxlength="30" data-bind="hasfocus:$data.isSelected, value:tempName, valueUpdate: 'keyup' " />
                <span class="rename" data-bind="click: $root.selectKiosk">q</span>
            </div>
            <select data-bind="options: $root.profiles, optionsText: 'name', value: profile"></select>

        </div>
    </script>
```

Comment: To get the best help here, you should show the relevant HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to get it on one line you could use the [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$(document).on('click', function( e ){
    $( '.profile:not(".default") .name:not(".selected") .rename, .kiosk .name:not(".selected") .rename' ).fadeIn(80);
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to simplify the code so that in the future I can add more classes along the lines of `profile` and `kiosk` without having to add more `fadeIn()` events. I'm not sure if it's actually possible.